# How to get rid of this "undefined" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have following JavaScript code:

```
var greeting = function (name) {
console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

console.log(greeting("name"));
```

It printed:
    Great to see you, name
    undefined

How to get rid of this "undefined"?

Thanks.

Comment: the `greeting` function has no `return` statement, so its return value is undefined.  It logs the message, returns `undefined`, and then you pass that undefined value to a second call to `console.log`..

Comment: @nnnnnn Included that in my answer :)

Comment: @nnnnnn Done :) Please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `undefined` is getting printed because, JavaScript functions return `undefined`, by default, if we don't explicitly return anything. In your `greeting` function, you are logging the string and not returning anything.

So, two ways to fix this.

1. Return the string from `greeting` function like this

   ```
   return "Great to see you, " + name;
   ```

   **Note:** As @nnnnnn mentioned in the comments, you don't have to concatenate an extra space character. You can simply include it as part of the previous string, like shown in this answer.
2. Or, simply don't log the output of `greeting` and simply call it like this

   ```
   greeting("name");
   ```